# grouping and subgrouping a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists, as follows:

```
tmp_lst = [
    ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker'],
    ['bobby', 'cool_j', 'corvin', 'forcemajor!', 'vito'],
    ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker'],
    ['bobby', 'cool_j', 'corvin', 'forcemajor!', 'vito'],
    ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker']
]
```

My ideal output:

```
    grouped_lst = [
        {'group': 1, 'subgroup': 'a', 'players': ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker']},
        {'group': 2, 'subgroup': 'b', 'players': ['bobby', 'cool_j', 'corvin', 'forcemajor!', 'vito']},
        {'group': 1, 'subgroup': 'a', 'players': ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker']}
        {'group': 2, 'subgroup': 'b', 'players': ['bobby', 'cool_j', 'corvin', 'forcemajor!', 'vito']},
        {'group': 1, 'subgroup': 'c', 'players': ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker']}
]
```

So each set of players belongs to a group, that gets incremented when there is a new group. And within every group, I increment the letter (subgroup).

I'm not sure of an easy way to do this.

Attempt:

```
tmp = []
for players in tmp_lst
    if players not in tmp:
       # initialise new group and subround
       d = {'group': 1, 'subround': 'a', 'players': players}
       tmp.append(players)
    else:
       # if the players are in the tmp list, I still don't know what group/subgroup they would refer to... 
       pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you are forming group and subgroup like that, and how do you ignore the rest elements. Please clarify it in the question.

Comment: Odds are this probably isn't the right way to structure this data unless you have some very specific need.  It would be tough to get meaningful results out of that dictionary.  Is the general intent to label unique groups and keep a sequence of the occurrences of the unique groups in the `tmp_list`?

Answer (score 0):

for the group you can try this :

```
 tmp_lst = [['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker'],
    ['bobby', 'cool_j', 'corvin', 'forcemajor!', 'vito'],
    ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker'],
    ['bobby', 'cool_j', 'corvin', 'forcemajor!', 'vito'],
    ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker']]

unique_tmp_lst = [tuple(pt) for pt in tmp_lst] # convert list of list into list of tuple
unique_tmp_lst = sorted(set(unique_tmp_lst),key=unique_tmp_lst.index) # remove duplicated element
unique_tmp_lst = [list(t) for t in unique_tmp_lst] # convert list of tuple into list of list
result=[]
for group,item in enumerate(unique_tmp_lst):
    for j in ([i for i,x in enumerate(tmp_lst) if x==item]):
        result.append([j,f'group{group}',tmp_lst[j]])
result.sort()
for i in range(len(result)):
    result[i].remove(result[i][0])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add a dictionary `groups` mapping list to their last `(group, subgroup)`.

```py
tmp = []
groups = {}
tmp_lst = [
    ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker'],
    ['bobby', 'cool_j', 'corvin', 'forcemajor!', 'vito'],
    ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker'],
    ['bobby', 'cool_j', 'corvin', 'forcemajor!', 'vito'],
    ['dimqaa', 'jenko', 'praym', 'sima', 'walker']
]
for players in tmp_lst:
    if tuple(players) not in groups:
       d = {'group': 1, 'subgroup': 'a', 'players': players}
       groups[tuple(players)] = 1, 'a'
    else:
       group, subgroup = groups[tuple(players)]
       subgroup = chr(ord(subgroup) + 1)
       d = {'group': group, 'subgroup': subgroup, 'players': players}
       groups[tuple(players)] = group, subgroup
    tmp.append(d)
print(tmp)
```